# PHP encoding problem in every page in admin interface

Tags: php, opencart

At first I thought it was a database problem related, but after some debug I found out that, for example, when updating a product if I output the `$_POST` results BEFORE saving in the database, this is what I get:

```
Array
(
    [product_description] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => ErgonÃ³mica
                    [description] => 
                    [meta_title] => ErgonÃ³mica
                    [meta_description] => 
                    [meta_keyword] => 
                    [tag] => 
                )

        )
    ...
)
```

So, whats being saved is `ErgonÃ³mica` and should be `Ergonómica`. Doing `phpinfo()` returns:

```
default_charset=UTF-8
mbstring.http_output=UTF-8
mbstring.internal_encoding=UTF-8
```

This is definitely a server/hosting problem as the same project in another server works without any encoding issue, however I have not yet figure it out what seems to be the cause of the bad encoding.

Anyone has any guess? The project was just duplicated from one server to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved** but I don't think this makes much sense..

I grabbed both `phpinfo()` from the server working without any problem and the server with encoding problem and the only thing different are the `mbstring` values:

**OLD Server (no-utf encoding problems)**
[image]

**New Server (utf encoding problems)**
[image]

As you can see some values are different and because I have no clue which one is giving me problems, by disabling the extension `mbstring` in cPanel, everything works now.